# Latest time to say asher yatzar after bed time?

Tags: sleep, bathroom, asher-yatzar

Say you said hamapil with shema and went to bed and immediately after got the urge to use the bathroom. Can you still say asher yatzar or once you head to bed you don't say asher yatzar until the morning?

I don't have the source but I believe the halacha is that if you wake up in the middle of the night to use the facilities, you do not say asher yatzar until the morning after you wash your hands.

Comment: Please [edit](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/posts/52733/edit) into your question some underlying reason why you think bed time has anything to do with this Berachah.

Answer (score 2):

From [here](http://www.jewsnews.co.il/2013/08/21/halacha-for-today-brachot-after-bedtime-shema/) :

If one used the bathroom after saying HaMapil, it is permissible to say the Bracha of “Asher Yatzar”, and it isn’t considered a hefsek (interruption) between the Bracha and sleeping.

After saying “Asher Yatzar”, one should repeat the first Parsha of Krias Shma and say some Pesukim (Shu”t Tzitz Eliezer Vol. 7 Siman 27, Shu”t Be’er Moshe Vol. 1 Siman 63 and many others. The Chazon Ish disagrees and maintains that it should not be recited, as it will be a Hefsek and render your HaMapil into a Bracha L’Vatalah. It isn’t clear how the Mishna Berura paskens in this case).